# ¿Cómo puedo abrir un vinculo dentro de la misma aplicación en un WebView incluido en un fragment?

Tags: java, android-studio, webview

Buen día, necesito abrir un vinculo desde un archivo HTML incluido en un WebView y a la vez este está dentro un fragment, lo que sucede es que cuando toco sobre el link este se abre en el navegador del teléfono y quiero que se abra dentro de la misma aplicación.

Este es el código del fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finformatica2, container, false);

    String url = "file:///android_asset/nitro/informatica/docentesInformatica.html";
    WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue esta:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finformatica2, container, false);

    String url = 
"file:///android_asset/nitro/informatica/docentesInformatica.html";
    WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view.loadUrl(url);

    return rootView;
}
```